# Qnx vs Android Vs iOS

Tags: android, ios, qnx

What advantages would a real time operating system like QNX bring to the smart phone / tablet space vs what android and iOS are doing.

Is really going to be more reliable and secure and at the same time providing great performance and security?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

It's very hard to figure out exactly what RIM is saying when they mean "QNX".  Yes, they bought QNX Software from Harmon-Kardon, but it's not like a QNX was selling a tablet OS out of the box.

QNX provides various components for the customers, including but not limited too:

QNX Neutrino RTOS -- a microkernel (with a few variations) that runs on x86/ARM/PPC/etc.  The normal development kit for this comes with the RTOS, all the standard UNIX/Posix utilities, a Windows or Linux IDE based on Eclipse, and a GNU toolchain.  You can buy it, and bring up embedded platforms and write C/C++ code to your heart's content.

On top of that, QNX provides various packages that provide other features.  They've got Photon, a X11-like windowing toolkit to make GUI apps, but it's really limited to making old-school UNIX apps.   They've got a Core graphics toolkit which allows for low-level OpenGL accelerated graphics.   They've got some Flash-running compositing toolkits for general purpose UI stuff.  Then, on top of that, they've got some toolkits and packages aimed at cars.

So now, when RIM says "We're using QNX", it's unclear about what they're using.  The kernel, sure, a lot of the underlying OS, sure, but the entire User Interface doesn't really match up to anything that QNX has publicly provided to date.   I consider that part of the system the most critical for user buy-in.   Comparing the details of the iOS kernel vs the Neutrino kernel, while interesting to some, is mostly irrelevant to the product itself.

Answer (score 3):

I think that discussion is touching just some very high level capabilities of QNX.

Some of important things:
This system is very mature from all points of view. It doesn’t have issues on kernel level and uses completely different architecture vs. Linux.
One thing is that you don’t need to rebuild kernel if you change something on drivers level or something like that.
System is much more stable and doesn’t have crashes on kernel level.
You don’t need to take tricky procedures to balance multi threads solutions as it is in Linux.
You have fault tolerant system by default and other things. Just read QNX capabilities in white papers.
UI and Applications part for Mobile devices (smart phones, tablets) still be architect and implemented but it tem of time only.
System is really scalable from single chip microcontroller up to Cisco variant and full Airport  Control System 24/7  (London )
Linux CANNOT be scaled this way at all.

So will see next two years...

Answer (score 2):

QNX has made their first attempt to enter in Tablet Market which I believe is not bad. But they have always been a pioneers in developing support systems for any hardware like emended systems on aircraft Industry (including F-16), auto-mobiles and other industries.

I have used Playbook, I believe its wonderful, touch is amazing better than apple specially with all-side touch swap option leave no room for buttons. Its microkernel architecture protects every application, driver, file system, and protocol stack in the safety of memory-protected user space. As a result, multiple third-party applications can run simultaneously on the RTOS without corrupting one another or the RTOS itself.Furthermore, its will be like first Multi-core / Multi Tasking Tablet and the best part is that Now Android app's can also be installed and run on Playbook.

Answer (score -3):

QNX is quite a bit heavier than Android IMO, so it will take something along the lines of the HTC Vision (TMobile G2) to get it running smoothly with modern software.

Funny enough, one of the airlines I worked for in the early 2000s ran their pilot training flight simulator, which had a complete 2 seat cockpit with QNX and an ancient 386 + coprocessor.  Most smart phones would kill that machine.